# Лучший способ проверки non-consumable оплаты во Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

На данный момент времени у меня есть проблема, с точной проверки оплаты продукта в моем приложении. Для этого я использую плагин [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase). Я хочу чтобы приложение проверяла точную покупку, чтобы человек не смог взломать его.

> Вот мой код для проверки

```
_verifyPurchase(PurchaseDetails purchase) {
    if (purchase != null && purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
      setState(() {
        dataHandler.purchases['advanced_training'] = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Так какая именно проблема?

Comment: Проблема, заключается в том что я хочу создать более качественную проверку оплаты

Comment: А это проверка не работает?

Comment: Она работает, но я бы хотел узнать как более сильнее убезопасить приложение от взлома

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В in_app_purchase есть [PurchaseVerificationData](https://pub.dev/documentation/in_app_purchase/latest/in_app_purchase/PurchaseVerificationData-class.html), который поможет проверить покупку [локально на телефоне](https://pub.dev/documentation/in_app_purchase/latest/in_app_purchase/PurchaseVerificationData/localVerificationData.html) и [на вашем сервере](https://pub.dev/documentation/in_app_purchase/latest/in_app_purchase/PurchaseVerificationData/serverVerificationData.html). Работает это все через [IAPSource](https://pub.dev/documentation/in_app_purchase/latest/in_app_purchase/IAPSource-class.html). Более детальная документация по: [Android](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#Verify), [IOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH105-SW1). Пример как должно быть в итоге:

```
_verifyPurchase(PurchaseDetails purchase) {
  if (purchase != null) {
    if (purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
      // Некоторая ошибка в покупке.
    }
    if (purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
      // Процесс покупки находится на рассмотрении.
    }
    if (purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
      if (purchase.verificationData ==
          PurchaseVerificationData(
              localVerificationData: "local",
              serverVerificationData: "server",
              source: source)) {
        setState(() {
          dataHandler.purchases['advanced_training'] = true;
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

***Всегда стоит понимать: 100% защиты от взлома не бывает.***